# How to get the array index in Lodash _.each

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, foreach, lodash

I'm newbie in JavaScript. I have a question

My code in Java:

```
public void checkArray(int a, int b) {
    int[]days = new int[]{5, 15, 25};
    int[]hours = new int[]{6, 8, 7};
    ArrayList<Interger> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < days.length-1;  i++) {
        if (days[i] < a && b < days[i+1]) {
            result.add(hours[i]);
        } else if (days[i] > a && days[i] < b) {
            result.add(hours[i]);
            if (i > 0) {
                result.add(hours[i-1]);
            }
        }
```

How can I write this code in JavaScript with Lodash `_.each`? I can't find a variable like [i] in JavaScript code, so I can't check the condition [if (days[i] < a && b < days[i+1])]

My code in JavaScript:

```
_.each(days, day => {
    //TODO something
})
```

Comment: Javascript uses the same syntax `days[i]` to access an array member. To declare the array, you'd use `const days = [5, 15, 25];`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Lodash [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach):

> Iterates over elements of `collection` and invokes `iteratee` for each element. The `iteratee` is invoked with three arguments: `(value, index|key, collection)`. Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning `false`.

This means that you can simply do:

```
_.each( days, function( day, i ){

});
```

So your whole code becomes:

```
var days = [5, 15, 25];
var hours = [6, 8, 7];
var result = [];

_.each( days, function( day, i ){
    if( days[i] < a && b < days[i+1] ){ // days[i] == day
        result.push( hours[i] );
    } else if( days[i] > a && days[i] < b ){
        result.push( hours[i] );
        if( i > 0 ){
            result.push( hours[i-1] );
        }
    }
})
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc3qdfLt/) to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

From [Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach):

> Iterates over elements of **collection** and invokes iteratee for each
>   element. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value,
>   index|key, collection). Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by
>   explicitly returning false.

`_.each` gets only one Collection to iterate as the first argument, and a function "iteratee" for the second argument.
So, `for` is a good option for you.

**However**, if you still want to use `lodash` you can get help from `_range` to create an array of indices, and then you can do something like that:

(in javascript of course)

```
let days = [5, 15, 25];
let hours = [6, 8, 7];
let result = [];
_.each(_.range(days.length),function(i) {
    if (days[i] < a && b < days[i+1]) {
        result.push(hours[i]);
    } else if (days[i] > a && days[i] < b) {
        result.push(hours[i]);
        if (i > 0) {
            result.push(hours[i-1]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript forEach in the array (no need to use Lodash) and it will be easier in ReactJS:

```
var days = [5, 15, 25];
days.forEach((day) => {
                  //do things with the day
                  window.alert(day)
                  });
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I must use Lodash :)